# Pointer to a pointer to a foreign string in Common Lisp

Tags: pointers, common-lisp, sbcl, cffi

Using SBCL, I am trying to call a GStreamer function with this signature:

```
void gst_init (int *argc, char **argv[]);
```

so I wrote this interface code (simplified) based on what I had seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841771/common-lisp-cffi-pointer-to-the-pointer):

```
(cffi:defcfun gst-init :VOID
  (argc :POINTER :INT)
  (argv :POINTER :STRING))
(defun start-gstreamer ()
   (cffi:with-foreign-object (argc :INT)
     (setf (cffi:mem-ref argc :INT) 1)
     (cffi:with-foreign-string (options "foo ")
       (cffi:with-foreign-object (poptions :POINTER)
         (setf (cffi:mem-ref poptions :POINTER) options)
         (gst-init argc poptions)))))
```

But when I run it I get a "memory fault" referencing an address that turns out to be an ASCII string of " oof", the reverse of the original string.  It seems I need yet another level of indirection.  Or maybe the defcfun is wrong.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I have not understood this completely but note that the second argument is not a pointer to a string: it's a pointer to an array of strings.